# ASP.NET Vnext error after deployment to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using .NET Full CLR and VS 2015 CTP5.
I am able to run a simple project locally on IIS Express but when I package and deploy to IIS, I get this error -

```
[Exception: Unable to locate project.json]

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +556

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +575
System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +726
```

Comment: Was able to figure this out from this article. http://codedbeard.com/asp-net-5-0-deploy-to-local-iis/

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps others. I had a similar error (without the "Unable to locate project.json" exception) due to my global.json file being invalid. In particular, I had used back slashes instead of forward slashes in the "packages" path.